# Power Display over USB-C

Tags: display, power, desktop-computer, usb-c

thanks for reading and trying to help me.

I recovered an old laptop screen and I want to transform it into a PC Monitor.
To do that i will use an LVDS to HDMI/VGA kit. ([This one](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1005001321633200.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.22725f8318ZCJU&algo_pvid=6919999e-21f7-4362-b1f3-ce0e318a0999&algo_exp_id=6919999e-21f7-4362-b1f3-ce0e318a0999-0&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21EUR%2127.38%2120.81%21%21%2129.17%21%21%4021038eda16927173667547922e1347%2112000015687836095%21sea%21FR%210%21A&curPageLogUid=VzMKKl6rwjMq))

I was wondering if i can push it a little bit further by adding a DC to USB-C adapter to power my screen with USB-C on a thunderbolt dell port by example.

Do you have and idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the specs of the screen adapter. Because the power available on USB-C depends on the "handshake" with a device, if you wished to do this on your own, you'd need to investigate what pull-up or pull-down resistors are used, or if an active interface is needed.

Comment: You can use a USB PD trigger cable but I don't think you can feed it off a PC, you would need USB pd

Comment: Mmm, I'm not sure of what you mean @DrMoishePippik, what do you mean by active interface ? Do you have an example or a link to show me ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, yeah that's what i was thinking about. And my computer currently have an USB PD

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery . If you are not familiar with these specs, this is *not* a suitable DIY for you.